# How to solve issue of Azure Active Directory multiple user login in same browser without logout?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I am using `adaljs v1.0.17 file` and `adal`, and use `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst`([my link](http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier)).

Value
this to get the user object identifier, in our application user can sign in using two different accounts in the same browser but different tab without logout.

When a user logs in with a different account, the old account should be logged out, or a second account cannot be logged in.

Comment: If you can switch to `MSAL.js`, it exposes [a function](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/docs/classes/_useragentapplication_.useragentapplication.html#getallaccounts)  called `getAllAccounts()` that will give you all users which the app has access to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but for MSAL.js we have to change our implementation also.